# docker build ignore existing data and database config stored in my volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, data-persistence

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```js
# some other services here
......
......    

#############################
# Setup PostgreSQL container
#############################

  service-postgres:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    container_name: service-postgres-server
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql
      - ./docker/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=db_name
```

Each time I try to rebuild the containers running force-recreate I lose my database schema and data:

`docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build`

But when I look under `data/postgres` I found that files and settings are there:

```
-$ ls data/postgres
PG_VERSION           pg_commit_ts         pg_ident.conf        pg_notify            pg_snapshots         pg_subtrans          pg_wal               postgresql.conf
base                 pg_dynshmem          pg_logical           pg_replslot          pg_stat              pg_tblspc            pg_xact              postmaster.opts
global               pg_hba.conf          pg_multixact         pg_serial            pg_stat_tmp          pg_twophase          postgresql.auto.conf postmaster.pid
```

How can I solve the issue and persist my database schema and data each time I need to rebuild the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why the database data get lost?**

I tried different things and compared the [MySQL image](https://store.docker.com/images/mysql) with the [PostgreSQL image](https://store.docker.com/images/postgres). Now I found the problem. There is no difference using a named volume or a mounted volume **but** you have to bind the [correct folder](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/103#issuecomment-167631242) on the container to persist the database data:

```
services:
  service-postgres:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    container_name: service-postgres-server
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./docker/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: db_name
```

You have to bind the `/var/lib/postgresql/data` folder to the host instead of the `/var/lib/postgresql` folder. You can also mount both folders to the host (the `data` folder and `postgres` folder) but you need the `data` folder to persist. On the MySQL image you only need the `/var/lib/mysql` folder to persist the data on the host.

**Just for comparison: The MySQL image:**

```
services:
  service-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: service-mysql-server
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_name
```

With the above configuration the MySQL data is persisted on the host.

**Using a named volume:**

```
services:
  service-postgres:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    container_name: service-postgres-server
    volumes:
      - postgresql-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./docker/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: db_name

volumes:
  postgresql-data:
```

With named volumes you can use `docker-compose down -v` to remove it. You can't remove a mounted volume with the `docker-compose down` command.

You can find the volume on the list of volumes with `docker volume ls`. You can also inspect the volume using `docker volume inspect <volume-name>` to get the mount point on the host machine.

Comment: should I use options such as `driver: local` for volumes or should I specify a local folder path?

Comment: try without additional config. the example above should work.

Comment: Thanks, working perfectly! But I when do `docker-compose down` then  I rebuild the again I lose the data. Is it actually an expected behavior?

Comment: @x-dai - I found the issue see the update: *Why the database data get lost?*